# Passing optional parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on SSRS Reporting Services with 2008R2.

ISSUE: I have two tables `Orders` and `Customers`.

I join both the tables and get the sufficient data.

My issue is how to pass `Customername` as optional parameter. I need to take this value from a query (I mean to display customer name in drop down).

To do this I have checked allow nulls as true for the parameter name: Customer name. But while generating the report it asks to select customer name.

I have also tried with:

Specified the filter condition of the dataset as follows:

**Expression**:

```
=IIF(Parameters!CustomerName.Value is nothing or (Fields!CustomerName.Value =Parameters!CustomerName.Value),true,false)
```

(Select `Boolean` in the second drop-down list)

**Operator**: `=`

**Value**: `true`

Comment: So what's the issue exactly? Can you populate the parameter query correctly? Do you want `NULL` (i.e. all Customers) to be selected by default? Is the report running but your filter not working?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered applying the filtering in the query?

First, set up the parameter, say `Customer`, based on a Dataset populated with a query like:

```
select distinct CustomerID, CustomerName
from Customers
```

Make sure it can pass `NULL` values.

Then in the main Dataset query text, you can use the parameter here by referencing it as `@Customer`:

```
select o.*
from Orders o
  inner join Customers c on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
where c.CustomerName = @Customer or @Customer is null
```

Obviously you'll need to change for your own specific tables.

If you want all Customers to be selected by default, you can set the default value of the parameter as `=Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the report parameter is CustomerName. Write the below query in the main dataset:

IF(@CustomerName = '')

BEGIN

SELECT * FROM Table_Name

END

ELSE

SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE Column_Name = @CustomerName

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply... I would like to know whether any feature available in SSRS for supporting this?